# Does the functional equation $f(x)-f\left(x-\frac{x^2}3\right)=\frac{x}{3-x}-\log\left(\frac3{3-x}\right)$ define an analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

When trying to solve functional equation $$f(x)-f\left(x-\frac{x^2}3\right)=\frac{x}{3-x}-\log\left(\frac3{3-x}\right)\,,$$
by assuming that $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k x^k$, we could get equations:

$$\sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor\frac k2\rfloor}{k-s \choose s}(-1)^{s-1}3^{k-s} a_{k-s}=\frac{k-1}{k}\,,$$
so that we could get
$$\begin{matrix} f(t)&=\frac t6+\frac{t^2}{27}+\frac{13t^3}{972}+\frac{113t^4}{19440}+\frac{1187t^5}{437400}\\&+\frac{877t^6}{688905}+\frac{14569t^7}{25719120}+\frac{176017t^8}{793618560}+\frac{1745717t^9}{26784626400}\\&+\frac{88217t^{10}}{15345358875}-\frac{147635381t^{11}}{19445638766400}-\frac{3238110769t^{12}}{827323540243200}\\&+\frac{63045343657t^{13}}{37643221081065600}+\frac{24855467017t^{14}}{7125970336860375}+O(t^{15})\end{matrix}$$
I have thought that the coefficients of the expansion above is bounded so that $f(t)$ is an analytic function. But after computing more terms, we could find the absolute value of coefficients increase rapidly after around $50$ terms, such as term $51$ to $60$ is around:
$$[78.513621003297250420074188707102682220, 202.58713829274578879553773336619242812, -449.99520262010819218204869756666128052, -1873.4863539770463771221218334858172231, 2366.9955239364074357260471634171465472, 17249.065560767631956266214434624779288, -8940.7592181048466843451670448875449069, -160960.78661872319570785726231645359908, -24829.450164495412949086768442609647625, 1533556.2377505922967945825482291368540]$$
So it seems the expansion above only provides an approximation of $f(x)$ like Stirling's approximation. So, my question is:

> Does the expansion above really defines an analytic function? Or does it really accurately defines a function?

---

Let $v(x)=\frac{3x^2}{3x-1}, v_1(x)=v(x), v_{k+1}(x)=v(v_k(x))$

We could prove that $c(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(3v_n(x)-n-\log(n)\right)$ exists for all x large enough.

It is easy to show that $c(v(x))=c(x)+1$ .

So $c'(v(x))v'(x)=c'(x)$ and $c'(v_{n+1}(x))v'(v_n(x))=c'(v_n(x))$ so that $c'(x)=c'(v_{n+1}(x))\prod_{k=0}^{n}v'(v_k(x))$

Since $v_n(x)=\frac n3+\frac{\log(n)}3 +\frac{c(x)}3 +o(1)$ and $v'(x)=1+O(\frac1{x^2})$, we could get $\lim_{n\to\infty}c'(v_{n+1}(x))=1$ and $c'(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}v'(v_k(x))$ uniformly converges and it likely converged to an analytic function.

Finally we could prove that $c(x)=3x-\log(x)+f(\frac1x)$ so that f(x) should be analytic function too.

Comment: The only thing of slight interest that I can see is that the functional equation can be rewritten as $$f(x)-f\left(x\left(1-\frac x3\right)\right)=-1+\frac 1{1-\frac x3}-\log\left(\frac 1{1-\frac x3}\right)$$

Comment: The background is that when analyzing the recursive recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=\frac{3a_n^2}{3a_n-1}$. We could prove that $c(a_1)=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n-\frac n3-\frac{\log(n)}3$ exists, and there's linear relationship between $c(a_1)$ and $f(a_1)$. We could use the approximation of f to find out that c(1)=0.37637275522427338461471882180513922234496462468342597627696829